# vpn is connected but its not working on browsers

Tags: vpn, browser

I run vpn(PPTP and openvpn neither makes any difference) on my Ubuntu.

In my country some sites like telegram ,youtube or twitter are blocked and I have to run a vpn to access them.

So after I run the vpn , telegram-desktop works well but the browsers do not work and all blocked site like youtube still can not be accessed but the normal sites can be accessed.

The VPN does not allow access to any of the blocked sites when I use a browser.

when i use both pptp and nordvpn firefox extension vpn is working fine and my ipv 6 is Not detected and ipv4 is not my real ip but when i use pptp without extension its only changing my ipv4 and ipv6 is my real ip and vpn is not working. how can fix this problem

Comment: What VPN service have you purchased? How do you know the State is not interfering with the VPN?

Comment: vpn is working fine in other devices

Comment: It may be a DNS problem.

Comment: so how can i fix it?

Answer (score 3):

disabling ipv6 fixed the problem and everything works fine now.

Comment: thanks its help me a lot